# Can I replace laptop's optical drive with SSD or other hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, optical-drive, asus-laptop

Can I replace my optical drive with a hard drive? I have an [Asus N61J](http://www.notebookcheck.info/Asus-N61J-X2.28088.0.HTML) laptop, I have seen some sites on the web that advertise this procedure for Apple notebooks. I would prefer not to have an external hard drive.

Comment: It certainly can be done for SOME laptops.  Hell, Thinkpads have an official adapter for this.  Hopefully somebody can chime in with details on this model.

Comment: This is possible, in fact the [Super User Community Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) has an upcoming post about this very subject - stay tuned!  (will post an answer to the blog post, when it is published).

Comment: @studiohack I actually dug one up!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing with Apple notebooks is that it's easy to produce one enclosure to fit several (or almost all) models, because it should seal the slot perfectly.

**However**, there is an [enclosure for your model at newmodeUS](http://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_36&products_id=304&zenid=ab2e0b7cb96f7542116afeefcc67cdd9), which comes at $44.75.

> Add a Second Hard Drive (drive size up to 12.7mm in height) to your Asus N43, N53, **N61**, N71 or  N81, N82 Series laptop using your laptop's optical drive bay.

One additional info though:

> Front faceplate/bezel is rectangular and black -- the standard faceplate is not an exact match for the laptop.  You can also transfer your optical drive's "original faceplate"  to our OBHD caddy.

[image]

Comment: I know it is possible, but just didn't know enough to write an answer... cheers and +1! :)

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this. The screw points were not perfect (I thing I left one hole out), but it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar and found this *very* well researched thread on a forum:
http://forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/388625-diy-adding-ssd-hdd-storage-using-optical-bay-caddy.html

There are just too many tips there to copy-paste here.

Update: Found the SU blog entry as well:
http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/04/best-of-both-worlds-putting-an-ssd-in-your-optical-bay/