# Install hdd where cd-rom is (laptop)

Tags: laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop: replace optical drive with an SSD or other hard disk. Is it possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/278209/laptop-replace-optical-drive-with-an-ssd-or-other-hard-disk-is-it-possible)

My searching skills are eluding me. For my laptop, if I want to remove my CDROM drive and physically put another hdd there, what is that hardware called? I searched for a hdd CDROM bay adapter but I didn't get anything.

Can anybody point me to what I'm after? Also, is this laptop make/model generic hardware?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Many laptops have removable CDROM drives and there are several firms making caddies which fit in the CDROM slot but contain a standard 2½ inch drive.

However laptop form factors are not standardised. You will need one specifically for your model of laptop. And that is assuming your model has a removable optical bay.

Answer (score 0):

NewModeUS produces a [caddy](http://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=2_27) which will allow you to put a hard drive into your cdrom slot.  They also have a [guide](http://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=page&id=3&chapter=0) to installing a new hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Duct tape.

Most hard drives have on the label a warning indicating not to cover a specific hole.  Obey that warning.

[image]